# What's the reason behind deprecating functions starting with create and replacing them with ones starting with make?

Tags: ocaml

Looking through the documentation, I noticed that a lot of instantiation functions that started with the word **create** were replaced instead with the word **make**. Out of interest, any reason why the language had to go through these changes?

Comment: For reference, I just checked `array.mli`. This was done at least 17 years ago. I'll try to find the mantis discussion.

Comment: Okay, `Array.create` was marked as deprecated 19 years ago. That seems to be older than the bugtracker. It is to be noted, `make` and `create` where already coexisting and `make` was the documented one (`create` was just next to it, letting the readers understand by themselves that it is similar). Most probably, that choice was made more than 20 years ago (but not that much more). My guess is, 19 years ago is when they started marking stuff as deprecated.

Comment: As a data point, this is not completely consistent: for example `Queue`, `Stack` and `Buffer` have `create` functions but not `make` functions.

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon so `create` is to create an empty imperative value, while `make` is for inhabited imperative containers. There is *some* consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know for sure. And the only trace I found of the decision is the commit message. For simplicity, I followed the modifications on `array.mli` but I guess this applies for the rest of the stdlib. Let's take a trip down the `git blame` lane.

As I stated in the comments, `Array.create` was marked as deprecated [19 years ago](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/commit/10270afb112bac01eebd018cf525de3493c856b4). The commit message is not very relevant to us:

> array.mli: documentation des cas d'erreur de make, make_matrix

Which translate to (translation mine):

> array.mli: documentation of error cases of make, make_matrix

This seems like the deprecation itself predates that, even though this is the first trace of "deprecated" I found in that file.

However, the two functions had been coexisting for quite some time. `make` was added (and immediately presented as the preferred name) in [1997](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/commit/c44e6f999a4b06a4b0e961e8607ab8c557501a57).

In the commit message, you can read:

> array.mli, array.ml, random.ml: create -> make (coherence avec String)

Which translate to

> array.mli, array.ml, random.ml: create -> make (consistency with String)

In that commit, `make` is added and documented. `create` is declared as an alias to `make` and not documented altogether. Which was probably the way to mark things as deprecated at the time.

tl;dr: Because they wanted to have consistency as the same behavior had different name depending on the data structure. Why did `make` win? You'll have to ask Damien Doligez (he is still one of the lead developers). Personal guess: `make` sounds more "imperative" than `create` does. But I may be thinking taht because I learned OCaml when this choice was already made.

Comment: thanks, 19 years is an awful long time to maintain a deprecated function!

Comment: Maintenance is mostly to "not delete that line in the code" and retro-compatibility is quite important to a language like OCaml.